# What is the common term for "Zeigzigler's Philosophy"?

Tags: ethics, terminology, practical-ethics

I went to a charity event recently, and the chair stood up and said

> My son is autistic, and I believe in Zeigzigler's Philosophy. That if you do good things to other people, they'll do good things to you.

Now on a simplistic level - this appears to be a Karmic idea. But I wanted to find the origin of what he was quoting. All my google searches came up with nothing. (Perhaps I'm spelling it wrong).

Has anyone heard of a worldview that sounds (phonetically) like this?

My question is: **What is the common term for "Zeigzigler's Philosophy"?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common term is "opinion" as it is misnomer to use the term "philosophy" to describe a way of looking at the world. Synonyms include perspective, zeitgeist, weltanschauung, weltbild or world-view, paradigm, sentiment, interpretation et cetera.

If you are looking for the Baptist Republican motivational speaker, you'll want to look up [Zig Ziglar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zig_Ziglar).

Note that philosophy translates from the Greek to respect (or virtue, reverence, love) for obtaining knowledge (wisdom). As a way of looking at things does not obtain knowledge, the term philosophy is misused to describe or categorize what Ziglar offers. Consider that if a way of looking at things obtained knowledge then an oasis and a mirage would be epistemically and ontologically equivalent. They are not.

It may be perfectly reasonable to believe "That if you do good things to other people, [then] they'll do good things to you" and acting according to such a maxim may even work for you, however, such is not philosophy.